# lxml unicode entity parse problems

Tags: python, xml, unicode, lxml

I'm using lxml as follows to parse an exported XML file from another system:

```
xmldoc = open(filename)
etree.parse(xmldoc)
```

But im getting:

> lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity
>   'eacute' not defined, line 4495,
>   column 46

Obviously it's having problems with unicode entity names - but how would i get round this? Via open() or parse()?

**Edit:** I had forgotten to include my DTD in the same folder - it's there now and has the following declaration:

```
<!ENTITY eacute "&#233;">
```

and is referred to (and always was) in xmldoc as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE DScribeDatabase SYSTEM "foo.dtd">
```

Yet I still get the same problem ... does the DTD need to be declared in Python too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eacute` is not a predefined entity in XML. To include an `&eacute;` entity reference in an XML file, it must have a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration pointing to a DTD (such as an XHTML 1.0 DTD) that defines the entity.

If the XML uses `&eacute;` but doesn't have a `<!DOCTYPE>`, it is not well-formed and the system that exported it needs to be fixed.

(There isn't a good reason to use an entity reference to represent `é` in an XML file. The character reference `&#233;` is understood everywhere without entity definitions, if the file can't simply include a raw UTF-8 `é` for some reason.)

Comment: I've tried adding the dtd, the file, but not doctype, for which was missing. But i still get the same error.

Comment: Make sure you're using a `etree.XMLParser(load_dtd= True)` (passed to `etree.parse()`) to make it actually use the DTD.