# Python xml etree DTD from a StringIO source?

Tags: python, xml, dtd, lxml

I'm adapting the following code (created via advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835077/lxml-unicode-entity-parse-problems)), that took an XML file and it's DTD and converted them to a different format. For this problem only the loading section is important:

```
xmldoc = open(filename)

parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True, load_dtd=True)    
tree = etree.parse(xmldoc, parser)
```

This worked fine, whilst using the file system, but I'm converting it to run via a web framework, where the two files are loaded via a form.

Loading the xml file works fine:

```
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(data['xml_file'])
```

But as the DTD is linked to in the top of the xml file, the following statement fails:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True, load_dtd=True)
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(data['xml_file'], parser)
```

Via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798/how-do-i-validate-xml-against-a-dtd-file-in-python), I tried:

```
etree.DTD(StringIO(data['dtd_file'])
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(data['xml_file'])
```

Whilst the first line doesn't cause an error, the second falls over on unicode entities the DTD is meant to pick up (and does so in the file system version):

> XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'eacute' not
>   defined, line 4495, column 46

How do I go about correctly loading this DTD?

Comment: Added a bounty as I'd really like a more detailed answer, using the code above as the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a short but complete example, using the custom resolver technique @Steven mentioned.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

data = dict(
    xml_file = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE x SYSTEM "a.dtd">
<x><y>&eacute;zz</y></x>
''',
    dtd_file = '''<!ENTITY eacute "&#233;">
<!ELEMENT x (y)>
<!ELEMENT y (#PCDATA)>
''')

class DTDResolver(etree.Resolver):
     def resolve(self, url, id, context):
         return self.resolve_string(data['dtd_file'], context)

xmldoc = StringIO(data['xml_file'])
parser = etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=True, load_dtd=True)
parser.resolvers.add(DTDResolver())
try:
    tree = etree.parse(xmldoc, parser)
except etree.XMLSyntaxError as e:
    # handle xml and validation errors
```

Comment: Your example works in isolation, but I'm using StringIO objects for both the xml_file and dtd_file - I can'y get it working with those....

Comment: I've tried setting data = dict(xml_file= xml_file.read(),dtd_file= dtd_file.read()) ... which (seems) to get me further in, but now I have - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 28: ordinal not in range(128) - I thought the DTD would pick up on this.....

Comment: Correction - UnicodeEncodeError was unrelated to your code. dtd_file.read() etc seems to have done the job, although I'm unsure if it's the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a [custom resolver](http://lxml.de/resolvers.html#uri-resolvers). The docs actually give an example of doing this to provide a dtd.

Comment: @Alfe: broken link is fixed now