# How do I stop etree from converting numeric html codepoints to non-ascii characters?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a function written (and tested) that converts non-ascii characters in a file to their ordinal values in the form of an html numeric codepoint (hope I said that correctly), but etree converts the coepoints back to entities when I parse the file. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

parse_file = cleanfile.cleanfile(file)
root = ET.fromstring(parse_file)
```

e.g. & #233; becomes é in my output file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample html file input.

Comment: And please provide code that can be executed. We cannot do anything with your incomplete snippet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python xml etree DTD from a StringIO source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817137/python-xml-etree-dtd-from-a-stringio-source)